# creating groups and Repeating tables in Infopath

Tags: infopath, repeating-table, create-groups

I want to create a repeating table in infopath for which I tried creating a group but when I right click on myfields, I find the Add option greyed out. Is it necessary to create group for repeating table? Can anyone help me out here.

Would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what type of infopath form you are implementing - there are various types of infopath form like form library template, blank template, and **list templates** etc. Out of these, **list template does not support repeating control.**

Comment: Thank you for coming for my rescue, Habibur :) I am working on a sharepoint list and wanted to add repeating table or section. :( is there any other option to deal with repeating data?

Comment: This is the limitation of SharePoint list level infopath form, there is no way we can add repeating control over there. So as an alternate you can develop a new infopath form and that should be hosted in the SharePoint form library not in the list.... and also if you have Nintex form product you can handle the repeating table in list itself, there in Nintex it is called as repeater control.